# Cypher code only creates the first column of CSV

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

[image]I use the following code to create a database of my CSV file. My CSV has several columns but after running the script it only creates the first column which is UniID, but not the rest. [image]

```
// Define constraints and indices

CREATE CONSTRAINT Uni_id IF NOT EXISTS FOR (p:Uni) REQUIRE (p.UniID) IS UNIQUE;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FOR (p:Uni) ON (p.Hochschulname);

// Import persons

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///unis.csv' AS row
CREATE (:Uni {
    UniID: toInteger(row.UniID),
    Hochschulname: CASE row.hochschulname WHEN "" THEN null ELSE row.hochschulname END,
    Land: CASE row.land WHEN "" THEN null ELSE row.land END,
    Type: CASE row.type WHEN "" THEN null ELSE row.type END,
    Hochschultype: CASE row.hochschultype WHEN "" THEN null ELSE row.hochschultype END,
    Year: CASE row.year WHEN "" THEN null ELSE toInteger(row.year) END,
    Anzahl: CASE row.anzahl WHEN "" THEN null ELSE toInteger(row.anzahl) END
})
```

Comment: Pls give us a sample of you file unis.csv. Ensure that there is no leading or trailing space(s) in the header. Thx

Comment: Thanks I have added the image of the CSV file to the post. The header doesn't have any space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j is case-sensitive so you need to ensure that the header is correct case.

Instead of row.hochschulnam use row.Hochschulnam and so on. When the header name is not match on your query, the values are NULL thus the properties becomes blank.

```
Hochschulname: CASE row.Hochschulname WHEN "" THEN null ELSE row.Hochschulname END
```